# How to stop Hyper-V Server 2019 from starting sconfig.exe automatically after each boot?

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2019

The Hyper-V Server starts sconfig everytime after booting up. 
I'd like to stop that.

Comment: Check registry keys `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` and `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`.

Comment: I’m having a little trouble understanding the problem. This tool should only start after you log in. Why log in to a server that doesn’t really have a GUI?

Comment: @harrymc got it, thanks! (how could I forgot the Run keys!!)